# How can I construct a range search on WPS search in geoserver

Tags: javascript, c++, graphics, 3d

In fact, I want to build a function that maps the range of the query. The polygon selection is the terrain list of the selection within the scope of the filtered image. I don’t have any ideas. 
[image: layer preview]

We started a geoserver service locally, and recorded some geographic information, and published WMS functionality. These maps contain common layer queries ,KML,and GML interfaces. Then we observe that this layer query is actually a query for the image
[image: we started]

You can see there is a sub-window loaded with a map layer. When we click on the image, we can get the situation information of the point in the map.
[image: point of map]

But it’s only limited to point clicks, in fact, I need to implement a polygon selection like boxing or circling on the maps follows
[image: polygon]

Comment: When I use the square box,It should return a list of all the terrain that the sure intersects with the square.May I ask who else has a better way ?please tell me! Thank you!

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it more clearer? remove the unecessary information (for eg: the "Your best friend! leo" part) and try to show some code that can help the community better understand your query. thanks!